# PyDev - Turn off autocomplete + hotkey for completion suggestions?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev, hotkeys

I am new to Eclipse/PyDev and I would like to change its default behavior.

First, I would like to turn off the auto-complete suggestions window that pops up while I am typing. I just find this distracting. I actually managed to do this by changing a bunch of settings in Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis/Code Completion, but I'm not sure which of the settings I changed was the correct one.

Secondly, I do find the suggestions window helpful *when I need it*. If I have autocomplete disabled, is there a hotkey I can press to pull up the window when I want it?

Answer (score 12):

For now, I have the auto-completion behavior like this: **only** when ctrl+space is pressed Eclipse rises possible autofill suggestions, in other cases the window is still clean. To end up having this result, you need to go to Windows/Preferences/PyDev/Editor. In the 'Code Completion' form unplug all checkboxes except 'Use code completion?'. And in 'Code Completion (ctx and insensitive common tokens)' you need to unplug all checkboxes. Hope this helps.

P.S. I use eclipse  Luna 4.4.2 with PyDev version 4.1.0.201505270003

Comment: Still works with ecipse-2019-12 neon3 and pydev 7.4

Comment: Unchecking just `Request completion on all letter chars and '_'` and `Use common tokens auto code completion?` made it more close to the C editor behavior.